# Org LaTeX problems with themes when exporting to html

Tags: org-export, latex, html

I use the two great html theme, bigblow and readtheorg, from https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes. They're awesome ! Looks really professionnal. The problem is that when I export some LaTeX, in both mode it's not good yet.

In bigblow, the font LaTeX font size is way too big ! Like 3 times the size of normal text. So I would like to change that size to fit the font size of normal text.

In readtheorg, some LaTeX sometimes overlap normal text, and also some characters aren't displayed like `\mathbb{K}`.

I like both so I am looking for two solutions ! First solution will be marked as the answer.
Thank you